# How to add yahoo mail into Ubuntu 22.04 Online Account?

Tags: email, evolution, online-accounts, yahoo

How do I add yahoo mail to Ubuntu 22.04 Online Account?

I tried clicking on IMAP and SMTP, filling in the Email and Name info, click Next and tried using the App Password generated by Account Security within Yahoo Settings or my usual password, I still get the error message "Error connecting to IMAP server" saying the "name or service is not known".

[image: imap_smtp]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not add yahoo mail to Ubuntu 22.04 Online Account. Instead, I added yahoo mail smtp to the Evolution package to access yahoo mail directly.  Go to `Edit` --> `Preferences` --> `Mail Accounts` --> `Add`

Comment: or the default Thunderbird package...